# How to create a hasManyThrough relation in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, laravel-5

I am trying to create a [hasManyThrough](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) in Laravel for my tables.

**Here is a high level of my table structure**

I have survey_questions table. (one question belongs to many controls `survey_questions.id = survey_question_controls.question_id`)

I have survey_question_controls table (many controls belong to one question i.e. `survey_question_controls.question_id = survey_questions.id`)

I also have survey_control_items (many items belong to one control i.e. `survey_control_items.control_id = survey_question_controls.id`)

I need to build a `hasManyThrough` relation for the question to the items.

**Here are my table definitions**

```
CREATE TABLE `survey_questions` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `title` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `survey_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `sort` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `page_number` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `is_required` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `visible_level` enum('All','store','region','district','division') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'All',
   `visible_to` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `visible` enum('Always','conditional') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Always',
   `status` enum('active','inactive') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
   `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `survey_questions_survey_id_index` (`survey_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `survey_question_controls` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `input_type` enum('text','textarea','radio','checkbox','menu','list') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `sort` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `validation_rule` enum('none','number','text') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
   `min_length` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `max_length` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `min_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `max_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `refuse` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `disqualify` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `status` enum('active','inactive') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
   `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `survey_question_controls_question_id_index` (`question_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

 CREATE TABLE `survey_control_items` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `title` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `control_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `sort` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `survey_control_items_control_id_index` (`control_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I am trying to get similar data to this question using the Laravel's ORM.

```
SELECT * FROM survey_questions AS q
INNER JOIN survey_question_controls AS c ON c.question_id = q.id
LEFT JOIN survey_control_items AS i ON i.control_id = c.id
```

In my SurveyQuestions model I added this relations

```
 /**
 * Get items for the controls that belongs to the question
 * Questions > controls > 
 */
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Surveyquestioncontrols::class, Surveycontrolitems::class, 'question_id', 'id', 'control_id', 'control_id');
}
```

This is giving me the following SQL error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'survey_control_items.surveyquestioncontrols_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `survey_control_items` where `survey_control_items`.`surveyquestioncontrols_id` = 1 and `survey_control_items`.`surveyquestioncontrols_id` is not null)
```

**Question**
How do I create a hasManyThrough relation?

**Edited**

When you read the error above you will notice the a column name that does not exists `survey_control_items.surveyquestioncontrols_id` this column should be `survey_control_items.control_id`

Additionally, based on the feedback below, my items() method should look like this

```
 /**
 * Get items for the controls that belongs to the question
 * Questions > controls > 
 */
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Surveycontrolitems::class, Surveyquestioncontrols::class, 'question_id', 'control_id');
}
```

Comment: I realised what I'd written was wrong which is why I removed it. Apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong parameter order for the models

> The first argument passed to the hasManyThrough method is the name of the final model we wish to access, while the second argument is the name of the intermediate model.

and for the foreign keys

> The third argument is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model, while the fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final model.

```php
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Surveycontrolitems::class,
        Surveyquestioncontrols::class,
        'question_id',
        'control_id'
    );
}
```

All of this would be automatic if you used proper camel- and snake-casing for your models and database tables and named the foreign keys according to the actual related table names.

Comment: Still same problem. Please look at my respond to Kevin's answer. There got to be a fifth and sixth parameter so accommodate the custom table naming

Comment: the intermediate key should be "id" and the final key should be "control_id" so I did this `return $this->hasManyThrough(Surveycontrolitems::class, Surveyquestioncontrols::class, 'id', 'control_id');` but the error message is still assuming the ids

Comment: Two people have told you how to use the hasManyThrough method now, but you insist on ignoring our advice. Please read the documentation. You'll see that the third argument in the method should not be `id`, it should be `question_id`. This is because it is the foreign key for the intermediate model. In your case, this is `Surveyquestioncontrols`. `Surveyquestioncontrols` must reference back to the parent model, which represents the `survey_questions` table.

Comment: @KevinLee it is not me insisting to be correct, it is me trying to solve a problem that still existing even after your recommendation. Anyhow, items() now returns the following `$this->hasManyThrough(Surveycontrolitems::class, Surveyquestioncontrols::class, 'question_id', 'control_id');` but still same error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'survey_control_items.surveyquestioncontrols_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `survey_control_items` where `survey_control_items`.`surveyquestioncontrols_id` = 1 and `survey_control_items`.`surveyquestioncontrols_id` is not null)`

Comment: @MikeA, sorry but I just tried to do it exactly as in the docs and it worked perfectly. If you look at the source of hasManyThrough, there is no sixth parameter and it makes no sense at all having one. There is a fith parameter for the local_id which is not needed in your case (only if 'id' on 'survey_questions' would be named differently. Please also see my advice on correctly naming your foreign keys.

Comment: @mniess thank you for your help. I am not sure why it is giving me an error in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This error may be because you are using the `hasManyThrough()` method incorrectly.

If your model classes are in the namespace 'App', try:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Surveycontrolitems', 'App\Surveyquestioncontrols', 'question_id', 'control_id');
```

Source: [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) and [API Usage](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hasManyThrough)

Comment: Still same problem. If you look at the error I listed in my question you will notice that the generated WHERE clause have the following column `survey_control_items`.`surveyquestioncontrols_id` which is invalid. it should be `survey_control_items`.`control_id`  I know that Laravel is assuming that the `surveyquestioncontrols_id` should existing but in my case want to replace it with just "id" i.e. `survey_control_items`.`id`